# How can I migrate a web app with Angular v7 to mobile NativeScript app

Tags: android, angular, migration, nativescript, angular7

I made a simple web app with Angular v7 and I want to migrate it to a NativeScript mobile app .

I followed the instructions in https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project#migrating-components but I am facing a difficulty.

The app is running in my Android mobile phone but it does not show the content because I need to adjust it properly for a mobile app. It shows auto-generated works. The problem is I do not know how I can do adjust properly the code since I cannot find a properly doc. Any help?

My code in **app.component.html**:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<weather-search></weather-search>
<weather-list></weather-list>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My code in **weather-search.component.html**:

```
<section class="weather-search">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="test_up">
            <label for="city" class="city">City</label>
            <input name="location" type="text" id="city" ngModel required>
        </div>
        <div class="test_down">
            <label for="countryCode" class="city">Country Code</label>
            <input name="countryCode" type="text" id="code" ngModel required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add City</button>
    </form>
    <button (click)="onClickLocationData(f)">Get geolocation</button>
    <label for="latitude" class="map" *ngIf="latitude!=0">Latitude: {{latitude}} </label>
    <label for="longitude" class="map" *ngIf="longitude!=0">Longitude: {{longitude}} </label>
    <div id="map" class="mapLocation"></div>
</section>
```

My code in **weather-list.component.html**:

```
<section class="weather-list">
    <weather-item *ngFor="let weatherItem of weatherItems" [item]="weatherItem"></weather-item>
</section>
```

My code in **weather-item.component.html**:

```
<article class="weather-element">
    <div class="col-1"> 
        <h3>{{ weatherItem.cityName }}</h3>
        <p class="info">{{ weatherItem.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"> 
        <span class="temperature">{{ weatherItem.temperature }}°C</span>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: `The problem is I do not know how I can do adjust properly the code` => How can I help you with, let me know? I recently worked on few {NS} code sharing projects.

Comment: @Narendra Hi! Thanks for the quick response. After running successfully the commands **ng add @nativescript/schematics** and **ng g migrate-component --name= ** for each component, if I run it on my mobile device, it works but it does not show the appropriate content. Now shouldn 't I adjust the content of each file that I posted? How? Can you give an example using my code?

Comment: @Narendra Hi! Can you also show me how I will adjust my form in **weather-search.component.html** ?

Comment: @Narendra hey did u create a repo in GitHub as you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that document suggests as well, you have to create component.tns.html file as  and other HTML elements are not available for mobile.

In your .tns.html file, you can replace  with either StackLayout or GridLayout. You can refer to https://www.nslayouts.com/ to learn more about {NS} layouts.

in your **weather-list.component.tns.html**:

```
<StackLayout class="weather-list">
    <weather-item *ngFor="let weatherItem of weatherItems" [item]="weatherItem"></weather-item>
</StackLayout >
```

and in **weather-item.component.tns.html**

```
<StackLayout class="weather-element">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="{{ weatherItem.cityName }}"></Label>
            <Label text="{{ weatherItem.description }}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="{{ weatherItem.temperature }}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: What about self-made components like <weather-item> in **weather-list.component.html** ? Can you give me an example? Thanks!!

Comment: I have added an example for you in answer. You can also create sample here at https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: Thank you so much! If you have any other sources for migration, it would be nice if you can share!!

Comment: Sure, I'll upload a git hub sample and will share soon!!

Comment: Can you create a chat room so that I can share my problem? I adjust all the code as you showed me but it shows again Auto-generated works!

Comment: Make Sure you are using correct ‘comp.tns.html’ file and GridLayout suits the best for Form as you can define row and columns